# Expose partial razor view into web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use elements of the boilerplate Login view in a React app.

In standard ASP.NET Core 2 Identity projects, we have

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
```

in `_Layout.html`. I want to expose this content in a controller, to get the content in a React app.

The idea would be to have in the controller something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginPartialAsync()
{
    return Content(await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial"));
}
```

However, I cannot get to know where the `Html` comes from (sounds to be a `IHtml<dynamic>`, it's not `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html`).

Any idea ?

Comment: do you mean the namespace of  `Html` class ?

Comment: It's a HtmlHelper class, see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `HtmlHelper`, you can use the `PartialView` method:

```
public IActionResult LoginPartial()
{
    return PartialView("_LoginPartial");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case the ASP.NET project doesn't have the directory `Views` but `Pages` which contains `_LoginPartial.chtml`, we need to provide:

```
    public IActionResult LoginPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("../../Pages/_LoginPartial");
    }
```